# Image is draggable only on x Axis

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Using kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js library how to allow the image draggable only on X Axis ? can anyone help me? 
In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LuZbV/23/), i want house image draggable horizontally.

HTML Code:

```
<h5>Drag the icon from the toolbar to the Kinetic.Stage<br>This creates new Kinetic.Images</br>The images on the stage are draggable.</h5>
<div id="toolbar">
    <img id="house" width=32 height=32 src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house32x32transparent.png">
    <br>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS Code:

```
// get a reference to the house icon in the toolbar
// hide the icon until its image has loaded
var $house = $("#house");
$house.hide();

// get the offset position of the kinetic container
var $stageContainer = $("#container");
var stageOffset = $stageContainer.offset();
var offsetX = stageOffset.left;
var offsetY = stageOffset.top;

// create the Kinetic.Stage and layer
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 350,
    height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

// start loading the image used in the draggable toolbar element
// this image will be used in a new Kinetic.Image
var image1 = new Image();
image1.onload = function () {
    $house.show();
}
image1.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house32x32transparent.png";

// make the toolbar image draggable
$house.draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
});

// set the data payload
$house.data("url", "house.png"); // key-value pair
$house.data("width", "32"); // key-value pair
$house.data("height", "33"); // key-value pair
$house.data("image", image1); // key-value pair

// make the Kinetic Container a dropzone
$stageContainer.droppable({
    drop: dragDrop,
});

// hangle a drop into the Kinetic container
function dragDrop(e, ui) {

    // get the drop point
    var x = parseInt(ui.offset.left - offsetX);
    var y = parseInt(ui.offset.top - offsetY);

    // get the drop payload (here the payload is the image)
    var element = ui.draggable;
    var data = element.data("url");
    var theImage = element.data("image");

    // create a new Kinetic.Image at the drop point
    // be sure to adjust for any border width (here border==1)
    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
        name: data,
        x: x,
        y: y,
        image: theImage,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(image);
    layer.draw();
}
```

Comment: If only allowed to drag horizontally how do expect to get the image in the box below itself?

Comment: no, i want image draggable horizondally after dropped in the box

Comment: You use the 'dragBoundFunc' to limit dragging: `dragBoundFunc:function(pos){
    return {
      x: pos.x,
      y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y
    }
}`

Comment: @markE Why not post it as an answer? It is the solution...

Comment: @loxxy, Thanks for the upvote! :-) Normally I would post a full answer with demo, but tonight I'm tired so I'll leave it at commenting.

Comment: @markE where can i use this function, guide me, thanks.

Comment: can anyone post a full answer with demo???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dragboundFunc` can be used to constraint user's dragging (for example, constrained horizontally)

`dragboundFunc` is declared inside the object: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LuZbV/

```
var image = new Kinetic.Image({
    name: data,
    x: x,
    y: y,
    image: theImage,
    draggable: true,

    // restrict to allow horizontal dragging only
    dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
        return {
          x: pos.x,
          y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y
        }
    }        
});
```

Comment: thanks @markE...In, http://jsfiddle.net/gkefk/32/ multiple image can be draggable...but i want only one image within multiple image to be drop at a perticular position, when i drop that image.how can i do this?help me sir...

Comment: @BirunthaG, I'm not sure what you're asking now, but I'm fairly sure it's not about horizontal dragging constraints. You might want to open a new question... ;-)